# MQ client connect to multiple queue managers

Tags: c++, multithreading, ibm-mq

I'm using C++ (ImqQueueManager )to connect from an MQ client to 2 different queue managers(on different servers) via SSL.

When connecting to each of them individually the connection is fine, but when trying to connect to both of them from 2 different threads only one can be connected and the other one fails with error messages (no reason:0 and ssl bad certificate:2939). Are there any connection options I should be looking to change when trying to connect to 2 queue managers from 2 different threads?

```
// Initiate the connection
mgr = new ImqQueueManager();
imqueue = new ImqQueue();
// Create object descriptor for subject queue
imqueue->setName(MQ_NAME);
mgr->setName(managerName_);

// Define a channel for client communication.
ImqString strParse(channelName_);
ImqString strToken;

pchannel = new ImqChannel;
// Break down the channel definition,
//form "channel-name/transport-type/connection-name".
if (strParse.cutOut(strToken, '/')) {
    pchannel->setChannelName(strToken);

    if (strParse.cutOut(strToken, '/')) {

        // Interpret the transport type.
        if (strToken.upperCase() == (ImqString)"LU62") {
            pchannel->setTransportType(MQXPT_LU62);
        }
        if (strToken.upperCase() == (ImqString)"NETBIOS") {
            pchannel->setTransportType(MQXPT_NETBIOS);
        }
        if (strToken.upperCase() == (ImqString)"SPX") {
            pchannel->setTransportType(MQXPT_SPX);
        }
        if (strToken.upperCase() == (ImqString)"TCP") {
            pchannel->setTransportType(MQXPT_TCP);
        }

        // Establish the connection name.
        if (strParse.cutOut(strToken)) {
            pchannel->setConnectionName(strToken);
        }
    }
}

pchannel->setSslCipherSpecification(MQ_CIPHER);

mgr->setChannelReference(pchannel);
mgr->setKeyRepository(keyRepo_);

// Connect to queue manager
if (!mgr->connect()) {

    /* stop if it failed     */
    DEBUG_DRV_USR1("MQClient: ImqQueueManager::connect failed with reason code %ld\n" << (long)mgr->reasonCode());
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you use different key stores for each thread/queue manager?  MQ can only reference one key store per process,  all subsequent threads will use the first referenced key store.   You could put multiple certs in the key store and then specify the label to use with each thread .... C++ API was stabilized long ago and may not have been updated to allow specifying a cert label.   If not you could call the C API from your c++ app which is able to specify the cert label.

Comment: See this response from IBM on a similar question about pymqi/C API:  https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/issues/244#issuecomment-843378463

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your reply. Yes, correct, I'm using different key stores for each thread when trying to connect to the remote queues. 
Been trying to call the C API from my c++ app but the MQOPEN function fails when I try to open the queue for input (MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF). I guess this option is not available when trying to connect to remote queues using MQOPEN? FYI I can open it for INQUIRE.

Comment: INPUT means you are reading from the queue.   You can not read from a QREMOTE.  Based on your response the only option you have is to put both of your keys in a single key store with different labels and connect using the C API or split in two processes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.